# cfquery causes java array out of bounds?

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion, cfml

I am getting a Java array out of bounds exception based on a cfquery (pulling data from a MS Access database), which is frankly very simple:

```
<cfquery datasource="dsnApps" name="GetApps">
    SELECT * FROM tblApps
</cfquery>
```

How can an array out of bounds happen, when I am just retreiving data from a database?

I tried the following:

- empty database table i.e. recreating the database table With no data in it -> same error
- inserting and reading from database on a specific record -> worked fine!

So it is extremely odd. Any ideas? Any other debug information I can enable?

The stacktrace from the error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at com.hxtt.global.v.int(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.access.u.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.access.u.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.access.z.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.l.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.t.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.dq.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.dq.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.bs.p(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.c0.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.c0.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.cl.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.cl.next(Unknown Source)
    at coldfusion.sql.QueryTable.populate(QueryTable.java:287)
    at coldfusion.sql.QueryTable.populate(QueryTable.java:216)
    at coldfusion.sql.Executive.getRowSet(Executive.java:314)
    at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:775)
    at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:685)
    at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:646)
    at coldfusion.sql.SqlImpl.execute(SqlImpl.java:236)
    at coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.doEndTag(QueryTag.java:500)
    at cfcf2ecfm1878607083.runPage(\\frigga\home\users\web\b2033\cf.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:152)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:349)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:225)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:51)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:86)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:69)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:115)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:107)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:78)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:91)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:257)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:541)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:204)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:318)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:426)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:264)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Comment: Are you sure the line number from the error is pointing to your cfquery code?  What if you specify the column names instead of returning all of them with '*'? What is the other code around that line number?

Comment: try compacting and repairing your database... and then if possible, ran as fast as possible to pick up a book on mssql or mysql and ditch access.  You'll have nothing but problems with it in the future.

Comment: *How can an array out of bounds happen* You may not be using an array, but it looks like the underlying driver is ... A very quick search on "hxtt and arrayIndexOutOfBounds" suggests [one cause might be indexes](http://www.hxtt.com/support/access1350905421.html). Agreed on moving away from Access, if possible. Access is a desktop database. It is not designed for web apps. IIRC, even MS recommends against using it for that purpose.

Comment: There is a reason why microsoft ships (or at least used to) ship a lite version of SQL server with access. The idea being that you build the front end with access while the database engine is SQL Server. For a web app ACCESS will cause you nothing but grieve. 

Access is a TOY.